# Implement global listener to pause code execution

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, selenium-chromedriver, junit5

I have this code which is used to pause execution of Selenium code:

`Boolean waitruntil = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='ngx-loading-text center-center' and starts-with(., 'Loading')]")));`

I have every test running into JUnit code. Do you know how I can implement a global listener which pauses code execution if loading bar is shown(detect using Xpath locator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution which is a bit more complex than using a listener would be to wrap your element with a proxy and perform the check whenever you hit the proxy.

Let the listeners listen to events and not change the test's flow,

First of all we need to create a class that will perform the check whenever you call the element:

```java
public class ElementProxy implements InvocationHandler {

    private final WebElement element;

    public ElementProxy(WebElement element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        this.waitForPageLoad();
        return method.invoke(element, args);
    }

    private void waitForPageLoad() {
        WebDriver driver = ((WrapsDriver) element).getWrappedDriver();
        WebElement loadingBar = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ngx-loading-text center-center' and starts-with(., 'Loading')]"));
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElement(loadingBar))
    }

    public static WebElement proxy(WebElement element) {
        ElementProxy proxy = new ElementProxy(element);
        WebElement wrappdElement = (WebElement) Proxy.newProxyInstance(ElementProxy.class.getClassLoader(),
                                                                       new Class[] { WebElement.class },
                                                                       proxy);
        return wrappdElement;
    }
    
}
```

Then you can call `ElementProxy.proxy(element)` which will return a new proxied element, similar to the behavior of `PageFactory` under the hood.
Last thing is to wrap it under your own `PageFactory` so you can control the behavior of the elements:

```java
public class MyPageFactory {
    
    public static <T> void initElements(WebDriver driver, T pageObject) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, pageObject);
        
        for (Field field : pageObject.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (field.getType().equals(WebElement.class)) {
                boolean accessible = field.isAccessible();
                field.setAccessible(true);

                field.set(pageobject, ElementProxy.proxy((WebElement) field.get(pageObject)));
                field.setAccessible(accessible);
            }  
        }

    }
    
}
```

Now if you are in a web-page where the loading-bar is present, use your new `MyPageFactory`, which will perform the check automatically.

If you do not need to perform the check, use the regular `PageFactory`.

Reference: https://www.vinsguru.com/selenium-webdriver-how-to-handle-annoying-random-popup-alerts/

Comment: I have one additional question to ask. I have a series of buttons to click. In that case how I can use this code?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `WebDriverEventListener` that can accomplish what you want. You could implement this listener such that before each command executed by selenium, the listener checks for the `visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='ngx-loading-text center-center' and starts-with(., 'Loading')]")));`, and if so execute your WebDriverWait. Without seeing your code I'm not sure exactly how you'd implement this, but here's a resource with some good examples.

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/event-listener/